# Calculus: Maxima and Minima

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with the following question about local maxima and minima.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Show that if $a > b > c > 0$ than the function

$$f(x,y,z) = (ax^2 +by^2 +cz^2) e^{-x^2 -y^2 -z^2}$$

has two local maxima, one local minimum and four saddle points.

Comment: I suspect you know how to start. What is the derivative? When it is equal to 0? Where is your work?

Comment: It's also important to determine if the function is defined on a compact subset of R^3.If so,it has absolute maxima and minima. By the way the problem is worded,I assume not.

Comment: Note: "maximum" and "minimum" are singular; "maxima" and "minima" are plural.  So "There is one local maximum" or "There are two local maxima" would be correct usage.  (I fixed these in the posting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum and minimum is attend when $df=0$, mybe you can use also the Hessian matrix (you can know if it's a Maxima or Minima by the Hessian matrix)

Comment: Could you please explain this? I dont understand

Comment: you find the points X who's $df=0$  If the Hessian is positive definite at x, then f attains a local minimum at x. If the Hessian is negative definite at x, then f attains a local maximum at x

Answer (score 0):

At any of these points you need to have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ and same for the remaining variables.

Comment: @Abdelmajid, Re: your suggested edit - by "same for the remaining variables" this user means $\partial f/ \partial y$ etc. also vanish, not only wrt (with respect to) $x$.